# Java Graphics fillrec() method with double parameters

Tags: java, graphics

I am working on a graphics project from university. I am trying to use the fillRect method from the java graphics class.

The problem is the method takes in integer values:

```
fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

I really need it to take in decimal values like double instead of integers. Is it even possible or is there a sneaky way to get pass this?

Thanks

Comment: Cast the numbers to `int`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, a pixel is a whole number, so unless you're doing high resolution printing, you don't really need a double value. Having said that, you could use a `Rectangle2D.Double` shape and use `Graphics2D#fill` if your really feel you need it

Have a look at [Working with gemoetry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) for more details

Comment: The fractional part of double numbers may affect the shading of pixels when anti-aliasing is enabled. Additionally, it will be taken into account when the graphics is, for example, scaled up with `g2d.scale(2.0,2.0);`. But in general. `g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x,y,w,h));` is the way to go.

Comment: @Marco13 *"when anti-aliasing is enabled"* - exactly, by default, it generally isn't, just saying ;) - And since there is no other way to supply `double` values when rendering a rectangle, there's the only choice :P

Comment: Also, the graphics object may be scaled using AffineTransform, in which case fractional values may make a vast difference.